# Object transformations not showing on object properties tab

Tags: animation, transforms, keyframes, properties

[image]

As you can see in the image, the cube is rotating, keyframes with rotation values were set up before, but suddenly the properties tab stopped showing the changes.

Comment: In the graph editor there is Delta transform, but you highlighted the simple Transform in the properties tab.

Comment: Thank you @FFeller, I was applying all transformations over Delta transform without knowing.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in your listed channels, it notes that these are delta rotations. Your screenshot doesn't show the delta rotations in the properties panel because it isn't scrolled down enough to show them. I suspect you set keyframes on the delta rotation channels instead of the standard rotation channels. This is how your channel listing would look normally.[image]